# Generating Sequence with Same Values for a Group

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've below values in a table:

```
|  Val1  |  
| 201900 |  
| 201910 |  
| 201920 |
| 201930 |
| 201901 |
| 201911 |
| 201921 |  
| 201931 |  
| 201902 |  
| 201912 | 
| 201922 | 
| 201932 |
```

The last digit is the level(0,1,2,..) in year 2019. The second last digit is the identifier which is valid for certain date. Meaning 0 is valid for 3 months in 201900 after 3 months new value will be added which will be 201910. Example, For level 0 and 1 there will be two different active records which are 201900 and 201901 at a given time. I want to assign same sequence number for these two records. The output should look something like this:

```
|  Val1  | Seq |  
| 201900 |  1  |
| 201910 |  2  |
| 201920 |  3  |
| 201930 |  4  |
| 201901 |  1  | 
| 201911 |  2  |
| 201921 |  3  |
| 201931 |  4  |
| 201902 |  1  |
| 201912 |  2  |
| 201922 |  3  |
| 201932 |  4  |
```

I am using Snowflake cloud DW but Oracle syntax should just work fine. However Snowflake doesn't have CurrVal option in sequence.
I am trying this but doesn't work:

```
> (SUBSTRING(Val1,6,1)=0 OR SUBSTRING(Val1,6,1)=1
> OR SUBSTRING(Val1,6,1)=2 OR
> SUBSTRING(Val1,6,1)=3 OR SUBSTRING(Val1,6,1)=4 
>     OR SUBSTRING(Val1,6,1)=5) THEN (SELECT  s.nextval FROM table(getnextval(test_seq)) s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the datatype of the VAL1 column is NUMBER then why not do it like this?

```
with test (val1) as
  (select 201900 from dual union all
   select 201910 from dual union all
   select 201920 from dual union all
   select 201930 from dual union all
   select 201901 from dual union all
   select 201911 from dual union all
   select 201921 from dual union all
   select 201931 from dual union all
   select 201902 from dual union all
   select 201912 from dual union all
   select 201922 from dual union all
   select 201932 from dual)
select val1,
  row_number() over (partition by trunc(val1/100), mod(val1, 10)
                     order by mod(trunc(val1/10), 10)) seq
from test;
```

**Output:**

```
+--------+-----+
|  VAL1  | SEQ |
+--------+-----+
| 201900 |   1 |
| 201910 |   2 |
| 201920 |   3 |
| 201930 |   4 |
| 201901 |   1 |
| 201911 |   2 |
| 201921 |   3 |
| 201931 |   4 |
| 201902 |   1 |
| 201912 |   2 |
| 201922 |   3 |
| 201932 |   4 |
+--------+-----+
```

**Update #1:**

What you are asking about is [`OUTER JOIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/queries006.htm#SQLRF52337). But maybe you need the functionality of the [`LAG`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions075.htm#SQLRF00652) analytic function? I also think that there is no need to order by identifier, because after partitioning by year and level, the VAL1 column value gives us a natural ordering in the resulting partitions.

```
with
  test (val1) as
  (select 201900 from dual union all
   select 201910 from dual union all
   select 201920 from dual union all
   select 201930 from dual union all
   select 201901 from dual union all
   select 201911 from dual union all
   select 201921 from dual union all
   select 201931 from dual union all
   select 201902 from dual union all
   select 201912 from dual union all
   select 201922 from dual union all
   select 201932 from dual),
  t as
  (select
     test.*,
     row_number() over (partition by trunc(val1/100), mod(val1, 10)
                        order by val1) as seq
   from test)
select
  a.*, b.val1 as prev_value
from t a
left outer join t b
  on trunc(a.val1/100) = trunc(b.val1/100) and
     mod(a.val1, 10) = mod(b.val1, 10) and
     a.seq = b.seq + 1
order by trunc(a.val1/100), mod(a.val1, 10), a.val1;
```

**Output:**

```
+--------+-----+------------+
|  VAL1  | SEQ | PREV_VALUE |
+--------+-----+------------+
| 201900 |   1 |            |
| 201910 |   2 |     201900 |
| 201920 |   3 |     201910 |
| 201930 |   4 |     201920 |
| 201901 |   1 |            |
| 201911 |   2 |     201901 |
| 201921 |   3 |     201911 |
| 201931 |   4 |     201921 |
| 201902 |   1 |            |
| 201912 |   2 |     201902 |
| 201922 |   3 |     201912 |
| 201932 |   4 |     201922 |
+--------+-----+------------+
```

The LAG analytic function:

```
with test (val1) as
  (select 201900 from dual union all
   select 201910 from dual union all
   select 201920 from dual union all
   select 201930 from dual union all
   select 201901 from dual union all
   select 201911 from dual union all
   select 201921 from dual union all
   select 201931 from dual union all
   select 201902 from dual union all
   select 201912 from dual union all
   select 201922 from dual union all
   select 201932 from dual)
select val1,
  lag(val1) over (partition by trunc(val1/100), mod(val1, 10)
                  order by val1) as prev_value
from test;
```

**Output:**

```
+--------+------------+
|  VAL1  | PREV_VALUE |
+--------+------------+
| 201900 |            |
| 201910 |     201900 |
| 201920 |     201910 |
| 201930 |     201920 |
| 201901 |            |
| 201911 |     201901 |
| 201921 |     201911 |
| 201931 |     201921 |
| 201902 |            |
| 201912 |     201902 |
| 201922 |     201912 |
| 201932 |     201922 |
+--------+------------+
```

Test it online with [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=288413a3bbfe2a24a53f1c2a30b44676).

Comment: Thanks @Andrei Odegov. This works just fine however something weird that I am noticing, if I want to get previous value based on this sequence I lost first record.                 `SELECT A.*, B.PREV_VALUE FROM TEST A JOIN TEST B ON A.SEQ=B.SEQ+1` Wondering why this might be happening.

Comment: I think its because there is no value before 201900 which would be returned as PREV_VALUE. Here I am losing 201900 record. What should I do to keep 201900 and show NULL as PREV_VALUE?

Comment: @django-unchained, thank you for your friendly feedback. I updated my answer.

Comment: Great!! Works fine. Thanks @Andreu Odegov. This was a great help. Appreciate you taking time for this.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Useful part are lines 16-17.

```
SQL> with test (val1) as
  2    (select 201900 from dual union all
  3     select 201910 from dual union all
  4     select 201920 from dual union all
  5     select 201930 from dual union all
  6     select 201901 from dual union all
  7     select 201911 from dual union all
  8     select 201921 from dual union all
  9     select 201931 from dual union all
 10     select 201902 from dual union all
 11     select 201912 from dual union all
 12     select 201922 from dual union all
 13     select 201932 from dual
 14    )
 15  select val1,
 16    row_number() over (partition by substr(val1, 1, 4), substr(val1, -1)
 17                       order by substr(val1, 5, 1)) seq
 18  from test;

      VAL1        SEQ
---------- ----------
    201900          1
    201910          2
    201920          3
    201930          4
    201901          1
    201911          2
    201921          3
    201931          4
    201902          1
    201912          2
    201922          3
    201932          4

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```